# What is the criteria to resync chain using proof of stake?

Tags: synchronization, proof-of-stake, forks

In PoW, nodes always resync their own chain to the longest chain in the network in order to respect the work the miners have done. In PoS, as I understand in its simplest form, the miner with the highest stake in the system produces a legitimate block.

Then, what are the criteria to resync the chain in PoS when there might be a fork or difference?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, I think this brings to another question that whether the PoS produced chain is temper-proof.

Answer (score 0):

I got an inspiration from this paper https://decred.org/research/king2012.pdf, where it says

> The block chain with highest total consumed coin age is chosen as main
> chain.

This is also one of the very early papers talking about PoS.

I guess then we can let nodes resync to the chain in which all the blocks add to the highest total stake by the winning miners.

Please comment. Thanks!

Comment: This article may be interesting: https://medium.com/@dsl_uiuc/fake-stake-attacks-on-chain-based-proof-of-stake-cryptocurrencies-b8b05723f806